# xcode Debug Editor area

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

in Xcode, why is my debug editor area showing me this?

[image]

how can i fix this show it shows me something more relevant/ easier to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out, just need to go to Product -> Debug Workflow -> make sure 'Show Disassembly While Debugging' is unchecked

Comment: Glad you solved it! Make sure to "accept" your own answer so this will be removed from the list of unanswered questions!